# how to access value from custom attr in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

I am working on my firs Vue project with ASP.NET Core.
In this project, I have an input box and because I am using asp MVC validation. I am transferring error message from the server in the **data-val-required** attr.

Not I also using vuejs from clientside functionality and I want to validate the form in vuejs. Which is working fine but I want to reuse this same error message which available in **data-val-required**

so can anyone please tell the how to access value from custom attr in vuejs

```
<input type="email" 
placeholder="Your_email@gmail.com" 
data-val="true" 
data-val-required="The Email field is required." 
id="Email" 
name="Email" 
class="form-control">
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at VeeValidate: https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate this can trigger errors based on front-end and you can also trigger it manually after returning a error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Vuejs [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) attribute.

```html
<input type="email" ref="myInput" 
    placeholder="Your_email@gmail.com" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The Email field is required." 
    id="Email" 
    name="Email" 
    class="form-control">
```

and then, to retrieve the element's attribute:

```js
this.$refs.myInput.getAttribute("data-val-required")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vm.attrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs)

> Contains parent-scope attribute bindings (except for class and style) that are not recognized (and extracted) as props. When a component doesn’t have any declared props, this essentially contains all parent-scope bindings (except for class and style), and can be passed down to an inner component via v-bind="$attrs" - useful when creating higher-order components.